# Suppress Escape Characters in Matlab

Tags: matlab, printf

I am writing a module in Matlab to enter the configuration parameters of my experiment to a file 'parameters.txt'.

Here is the module which does that :

```
for i=1:size(ParamSheetText,1)
    fprintf(fparam, ParamSheetText{i,1});
    fprintf(fparam,'\n');
end
```

One of the parameter is the folder location :  "D:\temp". `fprintf` is interpreting `\t` as a escape sequence. Is there any way that I can suppress the escape sequence or modify the code so that escape sequence is suppressed.

Thanks

Comment: I am really sorry. Yes, It did. I forgot to let you know. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`fprintf` is parsing escape sequences only in format strings, so you shouldn't be passing your data string as a format string (but rather as an additional argument following the format specifier):

```
fprintf(fparam, '%s', ParamSheetText{i,1});
```

I believe this will correct your issue.